# How to hit a url without port in celery worker

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I have been trying to hit a rabbitmq server hosted in ECS using my celery worker.

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://{user}:{password}@{hostname}/{vhost}'.format(
    user=os.environ.get('RABBIT_ENV_USER'),
    password=os.environ.get('RABBIT_ENV_RABBITMQ_PASS'),
    hostname=RABBIT_HOSTNAME,
    vhost=os.environ.get('RABBIT_ENV_VHOST'))
```

I can hit the server using ip address (such as, 10.211.123.104:5000). But when I give a url (like, rabbit-aws.sample.com), the broker url hostname is changed to rabbit-aws.sample.com:5672.
I am not able to remove the port, only change it to some other value.

How do I change this?